# Setting paragraphs with no style to "Normal"

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2016

I have a document where a lot of paragraphs have no assigned style (as far as I can tell). They look like "Normal" paragraphs, except the "after" leading is not what I want.

I can use Replace to find paragraphs with a specified style, and replace with another. But I can't see how to find paragraphs with no style (Word interprets selecting "No style" in the Format / Style list as meaning I don't want to search by style....)

Alternatively, can I find out what (internal/hidden) style Word thinks these paragraphs have? There are a lot more styles in Find/Format/Style than appear in the ribbon-bar list of styles...

Comment: Do the "no style" paragraphs have consistent fonts and features, even though there is no style name assigned?  If so you can just search based on those characteristics (font name, size, italics, etc) and replace with the normal style.

Comment: Yes, I think so. They have a "Normal" ish style. They have a "justified" format which I don't want anywhere else - if  one can search for that, that would do. Thanks (of course, sod's law says I finished manually assigning the styles a couple of minutes ago :( but I think I'll have this issue again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the paragraphs without an associated style have any regular set of features in common (font name, font size, paragraph settings, etc.) you can search for those and replace with the Normal style.

In this case, you indicated in your comment that it was primarily the Justified paragraph setting that you wanted to eliminate.  This can be found and replaced in Word (at least in Word 2016, though I suspect earlier versions as well):

[image]